# Rewrite react class into react hooks component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-class-based-component

Started learning react hooks a while ago but I don't know much about React class based components. I might be asking for too much but could someone can help me rewrite this code into react hooks:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios, { post } from 'axios';

class SimpleReactFileUpload extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            file: []
        }
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault() // Stop form submit
    
        this.fileUpload(this.state.file).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ file: [...e.target.files] })
        console.log(typeof (this.state))
        console.log(this.state)

    }


    fileUpload(file) {
        const url = 'http://example.com/file-upload';
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file)
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }
        return post(url, formData, config)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <h1>File Upload</h1>
                <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.onChange} />
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}



export default SimpleReactFileUpload
```

I am kind of desperate so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please show the code you tried, and so someone will help in a practical way

Comment: I just posted below the code I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Code I tried:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios, { post } from 'axios';


const SimpleReactFileUpload = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        file: []
    })

    const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault() // Stop form submit
        console.log(state.file)
        fileUpload(state.file).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
    }

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setState({ file: e.target.files })
        console.log(state)

    }


    const fileUpload = (file) => {
        const url = 'http://example.com/file-upload';
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file)
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }
        return post(url, formData, config)
    }


    return (
        <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
            <h1>File Upload</h1>
            <input type="file" multiple onChange={onChange} />
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
    )

}

export default SimpleReactFileUpload
```

I don't know if I am close or not. I am total beginner